# Codeigniter: UTF-8 in the URL bug

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, utf-8

First, sorry about my bad english.

Im using Codeigniter.
When I create a dynamic address in UTF 8, I get strange characters.

The url look like this: domian.com/article/שלום#.T9H1U9WRGSo

Instead of this: domain.com/article/שלום

The links look okay:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/article/שלום">Text</a>
```

But after I click on the links, I get a redirect to here (in all the browsers except IE):

domain.com/article/שלום#.T9H1U9WRGSo

Thank you all :)

Comment: it is not a valid ASCII byte (0-127 only)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the deal is that you cannot have non-ascii characters in your URL.

The character has to be translated or encoded.

1. Take a look at convert_accented_characters() and foreign_chars.php described in the text helper documentation;
   or
2. Take a look at codeigniter's urlencode(), which will encode the non-ascii letters to their proper % codes.

Interestingly, if you look at a site like http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9 the symbol will look correct in the URL because the browser is properly converting the % code to the
ש symbol for you.

Edit: Some people report that this approach works

```
$hebrew  = 'ס֑ס֒ס֓ס֔ס֕ס֖ס֗ס֘ס֙ס֚ס֛ס֜ס֝ס֞ס֟ס֠ס֡ס֢ס֣ס֤ס֥ס֦ס֧ס֨ס֩ס֪ס֫ס֬ס֭ס֮ס֯סְסֱסֲסֳסִסֵסֶסַסָסֹוֺסֻסּסֽ־סֿ׀סׁסׂ׃סׄסׅ׆סׇאבגדהוזחטיךכלםמןנסעףפץצקרשתװױײ׳״';  
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = $hebrew . ' a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

(honestly, don't blame me if the alphabet is wrong :P )

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for why Codeigniter may or may not *redirect* you to a `#` URL, but URLs cannot contain non-ASCII characters. All non-ASCII characters need to be percent escaped using `urlencode`:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/article/<?php echo urlencode('שלום'); ?>">Text</a>
```

Since the browser should do this behind the scenes as a worst-case fallback, I can't say this will solve the problem, but at least it's more correct.